# Is the T2 Trainspotting airport greeter from Slovenia for everyone?

Tags: analysis, t2-trainspotting

In one of the initial scenes of *T2 Trainspotting* when one of the main characters arrives at the airport and starts leaving the terminal, he is greeted by an airport greeter and is handed a welcome pamphlet.

The main character (probably noticing an accent) asks the pretty lady as to where she is from, to which she replies: "Slovenia". I watched the movie in a Slovenian cinema, can't remember all the details of the scene, but do remember being surprised.

Is this scene localized fan candy (meaning it differs by screening location) or is the greeter from Slovenia for everyone? Any particular reason for her being from there?

Comment: I'm 70% sure I heard Slovenia too in the Canadian version. She says "Velcome to Edinbruh", so Mark is surprised of her non Scottish accent and asks where she's from.

Comment: @pyb I did see the English version and I am 100% sure it was Slovenia. It was not meant to be pandering, but to tell about Edimburgh (which was seen as a pretty depressed location in T1) now receiving immigrants (later in the movie Spud remarks -obviously not too seriously- that he is one of the few local people remaning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She was written as Slovenian in [the screenplay](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/33796017)

> **RENTON:** *Where are you from?*
>
> [She smiles at him.]
>
> **TOURISM GIRL:** *Slovenia.*

I've checked the dubbing and subtitles on a few different versions and although there are slight translation differences, her *nationality* hasn't been localised for France (D'où venez vous? Slovénie), Hungary, (Honnan származik? Szlovéniából), Serbia (Izvinite. Odakle ste? Iz Slovenije), Spain (¿De dónde eres? De Eslovenia), etc, etc.

---

As to *why* she's there in this scene, the goal seems to be to disconnect him and the audience with the Edinburgh he knew as a youngster (dreary, depressed, inward-looking) and this new thrusting, modern, metropolitan, multicultural city on the move.